# Re-arranging a list of names in R from "SURNAMES first names", to "first initial. SURNAMES"

Tags: r, names

I have a list of names that look like this:

```
c("CASEY Aoife", "CREMEN Margaret", "MORCH-PEDERSEN Marie", 
  "RORVIK Jenny Marie", "MIGUEL GOMES Natalia", "ROHNER Maria-Clara")
```

and to display them in a table I would like them to look like this

```
c("A. CASEY", "M. CREMEN", "M. MORCH-PEDERSEN", 
  "J. RORVIK", "N. MIGUEL GOMES", "M. ROHNER")
```

There are challenges as there are people with multiple first names and multiple last names etc, as well as dealing with hyphens etc.

I've tried a function as below but not getting my desired output:

```
convert_name <- function(name) {
  parts <- str_split(name, " ")[[1]]  # Split name into parts
  
  # Extract initials and last name
  initials <- str_extract(parts, "\\b\\p{L}")  # Extract first letter of each part
  last_name <- parts[length(parts)]
  
  # Concatenate initials and last name with space
  converted_name <- paste(initials, last_name, sep = ". ")
  
  return(converted_name)
}
```

Comment: I  think regex should be able to deal with this, e.g.: `sub("^([-A-Z]+)\\s+([A-Z]).+$", "\\2. \\1", x, perl=TRUE)` but I wonder if there's any more complicated names that might break a simple pattern?

Comment: @thelatemail I think you need to add a space in the first group (changing `([-A-Z]+)` to `([A-Z ]+)`. Note that I placed the space after `Z`. This is useful to match names like `"MIGUEL GOMES Natalia"` which is not correctly returned by the code you suggested. I am curious why you added `perl=TRUE`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sub` like:

```
sub("(.*[A-Z]) ([A-Z]).*", "\\2. \\1", s)
#[1] "A. CASEY"              "M. CREMEN"             "M. MORCH-PEDERSEN"    
#[4] "J. RORVIK"             "N. MIGUEL GOMES"       "M. ROHNER"            
#[7] "P. FERNANDES-Da-VEIGA" "W. Van-DORP"           "G. De-VITA"
```

Where `(.*[A-Z])`  matches anything ending with an uppercase followed by a space. `()` stores the match in `\\1`. Followed by an uppercase, stored in `\\2` followed by anything `.*`.

Data

```
s <- c("CASEY Aoife", "CREMEN Margaret", "MORCH-PEDERSEN Marie", 
       "RORVIK Jenny Marie", "MIGUEL GOMES Natalia", "ROHNER Maria-Clara",
       "FERNANDES-Da-VEIGA Paulo", "Van-DORP Wianka", "De-VITA Giuseppe")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great with my example. I have tried it on a larger dataset and realise I have a few more complicated names with some lowercase in the surname e.g. `c("FERNANDES-Da-VEIGA Paulo", "Van-DORP Wianka", "De-VITA Giuseppe")`. Any thoughts on how to account for these as well as those in my original example?

Comment: See update. Hope this works for the other cases.

Answer (score 1):

`sapply` over each name a function to shuffle the name.

```
x=c("CASEY Aoife", "CREMEN Margaret", "MORCH-PEDERSEN Marie", 
  "RORVIK Jenny Marie", "MIGUEL GOMES Natalia", "ROHNER Maria-Clara") 


sapply(strsplit(x, " "), \(y) {
  j = 1
  for (i in 1:length(y)) {
    if (identical(y[i], toupper(y[i]))) {
      j = i
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
  paste0(substr(y[j+1], 1, 1), ". ", paste0(y[1:j], collapse=" "))
  })
```

Another option without forloop:

```
sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(y){
  ix <- y == toupper(y)
  paste0(substr(y[ !ix ][ 1 ], 1, 1),  ". ", paste(y[ ix ], collapse = " "))
  })
```

Output

```
[1] "A. CASEY"          "M. CREMEN"         "M. MORCH-PEDERSEN"
[4] "J. RORVIK"         "N. MIGUEL GOMES"   "M. ROHNER"
```